# Distributing an array among processes in a block-cyclic way

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I have a 8x8 matrix, stored in a float array, and I want to distribute it among 4 processes in a block-cyclic way in a 2x2 block mode. Something like this:

```
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3
2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3
2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3
```

I am trying to do it in C/MPI:

```
int dims[2] = {8, 8};
int distribs[2] = {MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC, MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC};
int dargs[2] = {2, 2};
int proc_dims[2] = {2, 2};

MPI_Datatype blockcyclic_darray;
MPI_Type_create_darray(4, rank, 2,
                       dims, distribs, dargs, proc_dims,
                       MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &blockcyclic_darray);

MPI_Type_commit(&blockcyclic_darray);
MPI_Scatter(input, 1, blockcyclic_darray,
            output, 1, blockcyclic_darray,
            0, comm);
```

The only blocks received are those indicated by X, only by process 0 (and not all its blocks):

```
X X - - X X - -
X X - - X X - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
```

What am I missing?

Using the same `blockcyclic_darray` MPI_Datatype but in `MPI_File_Set_view` + `MPI_File_Read_all` for reading the matrix from a file works perfectly, so I am not sure about where the problem with the `blockcyclic_darray` MPI_Datatype is.

After some further research, I added

```
MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_FLOAT, &lb, &extent);
MPI_Type_create_resized(strided, lb, 4*extent, &blockcyclic_darray);
```

between `MPI_Type_Create_darray` (output: "strided") and `MPI_Datatype_commit`. Now each block is scattered, but only process 0 receives them in the correct order, while others receive blocks with some strange displacements.

Comment: `MPI_Scatter()` cannot do this, you need to use `MPI_Scatterv()`